# Simple Flask example with pytest and application factory does not work

Tags: flask, pytest

I am new to flask and I have set up a simple flask example and two tests using pytest(see [here](https://gitlab.com/z-boson/simple-flask-example-with-pytest/-/tree/V0.1)). When I let run only one test it works, but if I run both tests it does not work.
Anyone knows why? I think I am missing here some basics of how flask works.

code structure:

- `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        from app import views

    return app
```

- `app/views.py`

```
from flask import current_app as app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

- `tests/conftest.py`

```
import pytest
from app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app = create_app()

    yield app.test_client()
```

- `tests/test_app.py`

```
from app import create_app

def test_index(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.data == b"Index Page"

def test_hello(client):
    response = client.get("/hello")
    assert response.data == b"Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your registration of the routes in `app/views.py` when you register them with `current_app as app`. I'm not sure how you would apply the *application factory* pattern without using blueprints as the [pattern description](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) in the documentation implies they are mandatory for the pattern:

> If you are already using packages and blueprints for your application [...]

So I adjusted your code to use a blueprint instead:

`app/main/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from app.main import views
```

`app/views.py` -> `app/main/views.py`:

```
from app.main import bp


@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'


@bp.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

`app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # register routes with app instead of current_app:
    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    return app
```

Then your tests work as intended:

```
$ python -m pytest tests
============================== test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-6.1.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/oschlueter/github/simple-flask-example-with-pytest
collected 2 items                                                               

tests/test_app.py ..                                                      [100%]

=============================== 2 passed in 0.02s ===============================
```

Comment: For me I didn't have to move folders or change my code but I just used your suggestion of `python -m pytest tests` instead of `pytest` and it passes tests.